# Web API access with JavaScript D3 library

Tags: json, http, d3.js

I try to access a Web API with JavaScript D3 with the following code:

```
<script>    

    d3.json("http://oberon.X.ch/X/v0.0.2/labs/X/devices/bela/channels/X?to=2013-10-22T22:56:26.000Z", function(error, data){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The following error message pops up in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://oberon.X.ch/X/v0.0.2/labs/X/devices/bela/channels/X?to=2013-10-22T22:56:26.000Z. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Does anyone have a solution to this error?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361893/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err).

Comment: Hi Lars, I still don't understand. Do I have to migrating all my files to the server with the same domain to make it work? If I open the link in the browser, I can see the json data without any problems.

Comment: The error message suggests that you would have to move it, yes.

Comment: After searching the internet, the solution could be based on the aspect "same origin policy" the keyword **jsonp**. In this case, I still can stay with my express web server, resp. localhost. I don't know how to implement yet, but I'll cross that bridge and come to it...